# How long can the spells exiled with Lukka, Coppercoat Outcast be cast?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-planeswalkers

The question is simple when does a creature exiled by [Lukka, Coppercoat Outcast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLukka%2c%20Coppercoat%20Outcast%5d)'s first ability lose "You may cast this card from exile as long as you control a Lukka planeswalker" ability? Is it when it is cast from exile? Is it when it gets put back in exile? Or is it when the game is over? On the off chance it is the last one then one could recycle a creature like "Farfinder" if it was one of the creatures marked by Lukka's first ability, right?

The thing tripping me up is that normally cards that give abilities like this state something like "until end of turn" or "until the beginning of your next upkeep" but this one doesn't which is throwing me off and making me feel like it must be something or that it must be affected by a rule I am that is along the lines of one that states something along the lines of "...when a card changes zones it is treat as a new copy of the same card...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can cast a card exiled with Lukka until the end of the game, but only once. As soon as you cast the card (or it leaves exile for any other reason), it loses that effect.**

Lukka's ability creates a continuous effect that modifies the game rules for the creature cards it exiles. As you noted, it has no duration, so it lasts until the end of the game.

> 611.2a A continuous effect generated by the resolution of a spell or ability lasts as long as stated by the spell or ability creating it (such as “until end of turn”). **If no duration is stated, it lasts until the end of the game.**

However, once you do cast one of these cards, it moves from exile to the stack. In that moment, it becomes a new object that no longer has that ability:

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence. [..]

Likewise, if that creature is later exiled through other means, for example [Eat to Extinction](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEat%20to%20Extinction%5d), it will again become a new object, and you cannot cast it again through Lukka even though it is exiled.

Comment: That was what I thought just wasn't sure, I had heard some people try to argue the contrary among my local play group so thought I might as well bring it up here. Cheers.

Comment: That's not a duration, but a condition. If you stop controlling Lukka, and then control another, you can cast the cards again. It's like "creatures you control have flying as long as it's your turn" or similar effects.

Comment: I don't think this is right.  The card itself gains the ability, it's not the ability that allows the cast.

Comment: I think it was correct originally... 611.2b says "**for** as long as";  Lukka doesn't say "for as long as". It says "as long as". Without the word "for", it's a different wording. "For as long as" is a duration. "As long as" is a condition.

Comment: Master Thief also says "for as long as".

Comment: If Lukka were a duration, then you wouldn't be able to cast the card if you lost Lukka and then played a new Lukka.

Comment: JonTheMon and GendoIkari are right. I didn't read the ability carefully enough and I looked at the wrong rule. Lukka's ability creates a continuous effect without a duration that grants a static ability with a condition to the exiled card.

Comment: It is a shame that they chose to use such similar wordings to mean 2 different things; "as long as" vs "for as long as", because it would be easy to misread.

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit because it was made as a result of incorrect statements I posted in comments.